# Documenting Request Payload in apiblueprint

Tags: rest, apiblueprint

I've got a lot of API endpoints to document and the payloads of the POST and PUT requests can be complicated. I am documenting them with apiblueprint. I really like the way apiblueprint allows me to document URI parameters. It looks good and lets you provide the reader with all of the information they need such as (required, String or Integer, list choices/values and provide an example).

When we look at the Request section, however I'm not seeing how to provide the same level of pristine documentation. The request sections that I've seen just provide an example request.

Say we are dealing with a simple payload that just takes an integer named id that is required. Currently my request section would look like this,

> Headers
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Body
>
> {"id":"123"}

Is the request body supposed to be this sparse? What is the best way to convey to my users all the constraints/requirements for my REST payloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to documen your request paramters (headers, body, etc.)

If that's the case, then use the Schema section, and write a well documented [JSON-Schema](http://json-schema.org)

for example you current simple request will look like this:

```
Request

    + Headers

        Content-Type: application/json

    + Schema

        {
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "id": {
                    "type" : "string", 
                    "required": true
                }
            }
        }

    + Body

    {"id":"123"}
```

Comment: This works it isn't as pretty as what api blueprint does for parameters, but this will at least let me convey to the users the information they need.